# Setting value of session with Ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript

I´m kind of new to using Ajax but I am trying to update the value of a session using Ajax. The Ajax call shoud fires when clicked on a button.

When I click on this button it also returns the succes function. I am using Wordpress with this Ajax call.

Currently this is my code:

Ajax call:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
                data: {click: "true"},
                success: function() { 
                    alert('bro it worked!'); 
                }
            }); 
});
```

functions.php in Wordpress:

```
session_start();

    function notificationCall() { 
      $_SESSION['clicked'] = $_POST['click']; 
      die(); 
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_notificationCall', 'notificationCall');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_notificationCall', 'notificationCall');

    echo $_SESSION['clicked'];
```

So my Ajax call returns the succes function containing a string with "Bro it worked". However, my session always stays my same default value of "false".

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like, for starters, you're missing including the action in your ajax call: `action: 'notificationCall'` will tell `admin-ajax.php` what function you want to run with that data.

Comment: Hi Caspar, thanks for the comment. I've added the `action: 'notificationCall'` But still my session always returns false even though I clicked the button

Answer (score 1):

For me, Session with ajax working with the following code snippet

```
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);
function start_session(){
    if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    }
}

// form submition 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_form_response', 'form_response' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_form_response', 'form_response' );

function form_response() {
   $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['formFiled'];
}

 //Session value
if(isset($_SESSION['value'] ))
{
    echo $_SESSION['value'];
}
```